# AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'v8SegmentationLoss' on <module 'ultralytics.yolo.utils.loss' from 'C:\\Users"

Tags: python, pycharm, image-segmentation, yolov8

I am trying to take extracted frames from a video and create masks for those frames using YOLO segmentation models. When I attempt to run the code, it gives me an attribute error.

```py
from ultralytics import YOLO
import cv2
import os

model_path = 'C:\\Users\\Analysis\\Video_Analysis\\best-maskmodel.pt'
folder_path = 'C:\\Users\\Analysis\\Video_Analysis\\Extracted_frames_idea'

model = YOLO(model_path)

output_folder_path = 'C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\Masks'  # Update with the desired output folder path

for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
    if filename.endswith('.jpg') or filename.endswith('.jpeg') or filename.endswith('.png'):
        image_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
        img = cv2.imread(image_path)
        H, W, _ = img.shape

        results = model(img)

        for result in results:
            if result.masks is not None:  # Check if masks are available
                for j, mask in enumerate(result.masks.data):
                    mask = mask.numpy() * 255
                    mask = cv2.resize(mask, (W, H))
                    output_filename = 'mask_' + filename
                    output_path = os.path.join(output_folder_path, output_filename)
                    cv2.imwrite(output_path, mask)
```

I tried adding the `v8SegmentationLoss` to the `loss.py` and had no luck.

Comment: "an attribute error". specifics? what attribute? what line of code? traceback required. [mre]

Answer (score 0):

#### Upgrading Ultralytics can solve this problem.

Please try -  `pip install ultralytics --upgrade`

I have trained **YOLOv8** on **Kaggle** and faced this problem on my device when trying to predict with **best.pt**. This problem was solved when I upgrade ultralytics.